# find a word from all files excluding 1 directory

Tags: linux, unix

I am using below command to find a word in all the files in my linux box. But now I want to exclude 1 directory and search should go on for remaining ones.

```
find /opt  -type f -exec grep  -l "Texttosearch" {} \;
```

Kindly advice.
tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't ignore initial search in all directories, but you can remove the files from specified directory after the first step.

```
find .  -type f -exec grep  -l "port" {} \;| grep -v <dir_name_to exclude>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob at regex's but I have been following a tutorial [here](http://gnosis.cx/publish/programming/regular_expressions.html) and it says that the ^ caret symbol normally marks the beginning of a string but has a different meaning also which is like logical NOT or !=

> The caret symbol can actually have two different meanings in regular expressions. Most of the time, it means to match the zero-length pattern for line beginnings. But if it is used at the beginning of a character class, it reverses the meaning of the character class. Everything not included in the listed character set is matched.

```
/[^a-z]a/
```

**Ma**ry had **a** little lamb.
    And everywhere that **Ma**ry
    went, the lamb was sure
    to go.

As the results show the lowercase pairings "la" from lamb are not picked up but the uppercase M from Mary (along with the a so "Ma") is picked up. The writer of the tutorial called the caret the "compliment" operator.

**Perhaps you could try using it with grep?**

There is an explanation for use in grep here --> [Regular Expressions in Grep Command with 10 Examples ...](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/regular-expressions-in-grep-command/) which shows it usage and explains it thus

> Example 10. Exception in the character class
>   If you want to search for all the characters except those in the square bracket, then use ^ (Caret) symbol as the first character after open square bracket. The following example searches for a line which does not start with the vowel letter from dictionary word file in linux.